# ContentNotes and ContentDocuments in Salesforce

Tags: content, contentdocument

How can I find ParentId of ContentDocuments though I have enabled the Salesforce CRM Content?

Answer (score 1):

To create a document, create a new version via the ContentVersion object without setting the ContentDocumentId. This automatically creates a parent document record. When adding a new version of the document, you must specify an existing ContentDocumentId which initiates the revision process for the document. When the latest version is published, the title, owner, and publish status fields are updated in the document.

> ParentId (Object - [ContentDocument](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_contentdocument.htm)) -  ID of the library that owns the
>   document. Created automatically when inserting a ContentVersion via
>   the API for the first time. This field is available in API version
>   24.0 and later when Salesforce CRM Content is enabled.